# Should [branding] and [sharepoint-branding] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I can't see any meaningful difference between the [branding](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/branding) and [sharepoint-branding](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-branding) tags. Should they be merged? Or is there a difference I'm missing? If there is a difference, then their tag wikis should probably be updated to highlight that difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is no real difference here. I've merged the terms. Thanks for bringing it up. There is a way to propose a merge. If you click on Tags, then click on the specific tag, there should be an option for merge. This will lead you to a page where you can supply what the desired term should be. It'll then be available for moderator review.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that there were several requests with identical titles, but didn't know about that feature.